# How to redirect to another route in Framework7 router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-framework-7

I'm using Framework7 with Vue in my project and having troubles with pretty basic stuff. In my f7 routes I want to have a guard on a `/` route which checks if user is logged in and then redirects to `/home/` another otherwise redirects to login screen at `/login/`. But with the current setup redirects do not work. Any ideas why?

`routes.js`

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    async: function (routeTo, routeFrom, resolve, reject) {
      if (isUserLoggedIn()) {
        console.log(`*** redirecting to /home/`);
        resolve({redirect: '/home/'});
      } else {
        console.log(`*** redirecting to /login/`);
        resolve({redirect: '/login/'});
      }
    },
  },
  {
    path: '/login/',
    loginScreen: Login,
    on: {
      pageBeforeIn: function (event, page) {
        console.log(`*** /login/ onBeforeIN`);
        // never called
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/home/',
    component: HomePage,
    on: {
      pageBeforeIn: function (event, page) {
        console.log(`*** /home/ onBeforeIN`);
        // never called
      }
    }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by Vlad himself on F7 forum [here](https://forum.framework7.io/t/how-to-redirect-to-another-route-in-framework7-router/12318/3):

`async` is not for redirects, you need to use route’s beforeEnter (https://framework7.io/docs/routes.html#route-before-enter-leave 1) for this:

```
beforeEnter(to, from, resolve, reject) {
  const router = this;
  if (/* need redirect */) {
    reject();
    router.navigate('/another-path/');
    return;
  }
  resolve();
}
```

In addition to this my issue what that I had `loginScreen: Login,` instead of `component: Login,` in login route.

Making both changes did resolve the issue.